# Pdf is not getting opened in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I have a pdf link in my html page. It was like ,

```
<a href="http://www.abc.com/tandc.pdf" target="_blank">Click here</a>
```

A click on this link will open the pdf in a new tab for all the browsers except IE.In IE the pdf cannot be opened. In IE the new tab was opening followed by the error window 'Internet Explorer has stopped working'.Closing this error box will throw a website restore error.How can I open this pdf in IE then?

Comment: What happens if you try to open the same PDF "manually" in Internet Explorer (ie by dropping the PDF file on the IE icon on your desktop)? It might be an issue with the actual PDF file and/or a buggy reader integrated in your IE installation.

Comment: @JørnSchou-Rode: Getting same issue doing that also.